# How to close all inspector windows with a shortcut

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

Is there a shortcut to close all inspector windows ? and if not how I close the window of a selected inspector ?

Basically I accidentally opened over 1000 inspector windows and i want to close them all now because they have occupied the entire GUI and I cant do anything other than closing them on by one. I cant open the world menu or open a new window because they take not only the entire window but also they are always on top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bring up the halos [1] on the TaskBarMorph [2] and click the top left halo to delete it from the World.

1. If two-way halo cycling is enabled in the settings, Alt-click on Mac. Otherwise, Alt-Shift-Click to cycle to the TaskBarMorph through the morphs in front of it.
2. In your case, your problem is that it's covering the entire screen, so you should be able to click anywhere to bring up the halos.

Then, to actually close the windows, use something like:

```
World submorphs do: [ :e |  
    [ (e model model model isKindOf: InspectorNavigator) ifTrue: [ e delete ] ] 
        on: Error 
        do: [ ] ]
```

Comment: See my answer. Also even if this is doable I think this wont delete the inspectors but only the taskbar.

Comment: Yes, but you rejected the previous answer because the task bar was in the way. This answer removes the task bar, and you use a fairly simple loop to close them...

Comment: ok I tried your solution and it works, please add code to add the taskbar back and if you can code to map the whole process to a shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the following in a Pharo 3.

```
UITheme inspect.
```

And then did a World inspect to come to the following.

```
(World submorphs select: 
    [ :each | each class = TickingSpecWindow  ]) 
do:
    [:insp | insp delete]
```

You should be more specific in your select if you only want the inspector windows,
explore uses the same class.

Comment: Instead of `World submorphs select:` you can also use `World windowsSatisfying:`

Comment: @MartinW Ah, nice, didn't  know that.

Comment: this won't work with the bug I have described but thanks for sharing .

Comment: @Kilon There is the *Emergency Evaluator* which appears outside of the Morphic World. Now if there was a way to open it without using the World Menu you could close these Inspectors from the Emergency Evaluator.

Comment: yeap that sounds like a ideal solution to me Martin

Comment: @Kilon Please tell us, if you found a way how to open it without using the World Menu.

Comment: Martin its no longer needed because my problem was a bug and the awesome pharo developers have fixed it. Other than this I have never had a catastrophic morphic event like this.